# AndoridManifest Permissions Ignored

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I have set in my android manifest the following permissions:

```
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="27" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS_PRIVILEGED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <application android:label="MyApp" android:icon="@drawable/icon">
```

But if a take a look at the app settings on my phone, the app has no permissions set. Should the app not asking me if I want give this grant on installation?
Thanks

Comment: the app has no permission set.. yes that is the default behaviour.. if you want to prompt the dialog asking all these permissions, you need to write a code for that..

Comment: Did you accept the permissions while using your app? When app is needed for some permission, the dialog for asking permissions must be showed.

Comment: what now? i have to write a custom code for do that or is there a android default behavior?

Comment: not a default behavior anymore from api 23.. you need to ask it at run time.. that means write a code for it and prompt the dialog to user

Answer (score 2):

Android permissions work like this :

If your permission is **normal permission** it will be auto-granted.

If we are talking about **dangerous permissions** it goes like this :

- If the device API level is <= 22 / `targetSdkVersion` is 22 or lower:

  In that case, the user will be asked (by the system) in the install time to grant all the dangerous permissions for the app.
- If the device API level is > 22 **and** `targetSdkVersion` is above 22:

  The user will not accept dangerous permissions at install time.
  You must ask the user to grant access to the dangerous permissions at runtime - when you do ask your user to give access to those permissions on run time he will see system dialog
  that asks him to accept or decline the permissions.

So if your app did not ask permission at install time it may have higher API level.

For more information, you can check [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview)

Comment: one stupid question where I must but the checkSelfPermission stuff?

Comment: Simply - if you want to use anything that got dangerous permission(send SMS, camera, etc...) and the device API level is > 22 and targetSdkVersion is above 22 you will have to check if the permission is granted.

Comment: And there are no stupid questions - from every question you learn something new.

Comment: is there any specific point (class) or everywhere i want to do this check?

Comment: I like to use [this library](https://github.com/googlesamples/easypermissions), but it is just my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this.

Write a function to add the needed permission to a list

```
private boolean addPermission(List<String> permissionsList, String permission) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            permissionsList.add(permission);
            // Check for Rationale Option
            return shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(permission);
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Add a function to create the list

```
private void requestPermissions() {
    List<String> permissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<String>();
    final List<String> permissionsList = new ArrayList<String>();

    if (!addPermission(permissionsList, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION))
        permissionsNeeded.add("Location");
    if (!addPermission(permissionsList, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE))
        permissionsNeeded.add("Read");
    if (!addPermission(permissionsList, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE))
        permissionsNeeded.add("Write");
    // add all your permissions needed except normal permissions

    if (permissionsList.size() > 0) {
        if (permissionsNeeded.size() > 0) {
            // Need Rationale
            StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder("You need to grant access to: \n- " + permissionsNeeded.get(0));
            for (int i = 1; i < permissionsNeeded.size(); i++)
                message.append("\n- ").append(permissionsNeeded.get(i));
            showMessageOKCancel(message.toString(),
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                                requestPermissions(permissionsList.toArray(new String[permissionsList.size()]),
                                        REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
                            }
                        }
                    }, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            finish();
                        }
                    });
            return;
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            requestPermissions(permissionsList.toArray(new String[permissionsList.size()]),
                    REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
        }
    }
}
```

Then, override the activity function `onRequestPermissionsResult`

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS:

            Map<String, Integer> perms = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
            // Initial
            perms.put(ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
            // Fill with results
            for (int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++)
                perms.put(permissions[i], grantResults[i]);
            // Test ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION (if needed) or other permission
            if (perms.get(ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Permission Denied
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Some Permission is Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }

            break;
        default:
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}
```

On your `MainActivity` in `onCreate`call `requestPermissions();`